# Misconception related to Resultant of Vectors

Tags: vectors, resultant

I have read in many books that the triangle law gives us resulatant of two vectors.

$Question$ : How do we knew that the resultant is sum of two vectors not the product of the two vectors??

Clearly , I mean that, the resultant is due to two given vectors(fact) , but what is the gurantee that the resultant is sum of the two.

Answer (score 1):

The triangle law is how you *define* vector addition.